# App/API authentication approach advice

Tags: node.js, cordova, authentication, api-design, auth0

I'm building a mobile app (Ionic/Cordova) and it will call an API (NodeJS) and I'm trying to come up with a simple and effective user authentication approach that can both:

1. Sign the user in to the mobile app and
2. Protect the API so that only a signed in user can call the API
3. The API can identify which user is calling it

Ideally, I'd use something like Auth0 to sign the user in to the app because I don't want to deal with passwords etc.

So I understand I can build my HTML5/Javascript app and using Auth0 and it will log the user into the app, but the part I'm trying to understand is how do I set it up so when user is logged in and their app calls the NodeJS API, the API code will know who the user is?

Can I just use the NodeJS passport module for Auth0 and just pass the tokens from the app to the API and like magic it will work? Or will I need to do something different in the API itself like build an oauth mechanism?

Any advice on how to protect the API in this scenario would be appreciated. I ideally don't want to build my own authentication/token system in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes passport can help you to develop siple authnetication mechanism too. like username passoword. login  once and stay logged in for some time.

[check this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/)

To get the tokem you have to add signin API. in the signin API you verify username and password. then generate a jwt token and pass to client.

```
 var token = jwt.encode(user, config.secret);
```

Now In you mobile app At client side you can save as cookie or local storage .

```
window.localStorage.setItem('token', 'the-long-access-token');
```

Then after whenever you call API which are restricted. you pass the token. like this

```
var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');

 if (token) {
   $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
      'x-access-token': token
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, was not after information about how the client app. I want to know how I should protect the API. Is simply checking that the client app is passing an ID_TOKEN enough?

Comment: Yes if by protect you mean authenticated. then obviously thats what the whole thing I wrote  above. the token is generated only after signing in. nd its tough to attack that.

Comment: IF I literally go by word Protrcting API means, the medium is unknown. IN that case you can add extra key called API key as parameter of signing in. which is unique only for that app.

Comment: So how do i protect the API using the token passed by the users app?

Comment: this API key is like developer API key and secrete generated by favebook, to allow only authorised developer

Comment: I don't want an API Key ... that is only for server-server flows.   I am talking about a user with a mobile app, logging in with Auth0 and then their app calling the API.   I want to protect my API using the tokens generated when the user logs in to Auth0 (or a similar service)